# Spring Scheduled job with cron, only for the next 3 days

Tags: cron, spring-scheduled

I am trying to run a method every 10 minutes for the next 3 days and only that.

I have tried this :

```
cron.expression=0 */10 * * * ?
```

This will run every 10 minutes every day, every month.

But I only want it to be limited to the next 3 days starting from NOW.

I just can't find how to use (now -> 3 days) in cron

I am using this [website](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html) and Spring scheduler [Spring scheduler doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html) without success

Comment: How do you define 'the next 3 days'? Is it going to be 'the next 3 days' every time you restart your application/server? or only one SINGLE time from today?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Spring specs you can't define this logic directly in to the cron record. You should add such logic in to the program you run with this cron